# Safari hanging when running an ajax function

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, post, safari

I have a registration form that onsubmit runs a validation javascript function to check that

**a**:all the boxes have a value in them.

**b**:the password values match.

**c**: the email address is valid.

The email validation script makes an ajax call to check to see if the email address has been registered before.

It runs great in all browsers except Safari. In Safari it just hangs the page.

Heres the relevant parts of the code:

**html form**

```
    <form name="login" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($pre_link.'register3.php'); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validateReg();">
      <div id="register_label">Email Address:<span id="req">*</span></div>
      <input class="register_input" id="myregusername" name="myusername" size="14"/><br><br> 
      <div id="register_label">Password:<span id="req">*</span></div>
      <input class="register_input" id="mypassword" name="mypassword" size="14" type="password"/><br><br>
      <div id="register_label">Confirm Password:<span id="req">*</span></div>
      <input class="register_input" id="mypassword1" name="mypassword1" size="14" type="password"/><br><br>                              
      <br /><br />           
      <input type="submit" id="loginBtn" name="submit" value="Next" />     
   </form>
```

**the js validation code**

```
  function validateReg(){
    var origBorder = "1px solid #CCCCCC";
    var errorBorder = "1px solid red";  

    var myregusername = document.getElementById("myregusername");       
    var mypassword = document.getElementById("mypassword");             
    var mypassword1 = document.getElementById("mypassword1");       

    var errorstr = "";
    var error = false;  

    myregusername.style.border = origBorder;        
    mypassword.style.border = origBorder;       
    mypassword1.style.border = origBorder;          

    if(myregusername.value.length == 0) {
       errorstr = errorstr + "\n" + "Please enter your email address";
       error = true;
       myregusername.style.border = errorBorder;
    }

    if(mypassword.value.length<=5) {
       errorstr = errorstr + "\n" + "Please enter your password that is at least 6 characters long";
       error = true;
       mypassword.style.border = errorBorder;           
    }

    if(mypassword1.value!=mypassword.value) {
        errorstr = errorstr + "\n" + "Your passwords do not match";
        error = true;
        mypassword.style.border = errorBorder;
        mypassword1.style.border = errorBorder;         
    }

    if(error) {
       alert(errorstr);
   return false;            
    } else {
      if (checkMail()){                     
         return true;
      } else {              
        return false;
      } 
   }
}
```

**ajax code**

```
    function checkMail(){   
       var myusername = document.getElementById("myregusername") ;      
       var filter  = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
       if (filter.test(myusername.value)) { 
           function checkMail3(){   
    var myusername = document.getElementById("myregusername").value ;       
    var filter  = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if (filter.test(myusername)){
               $.ajax({
                  url: "checkregemail.php",
                  type: "post",
                  headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
                  data:{ username : myusername },
                  success: function(data) {
                      if(data=='1'){
                        alert("sorry this email address has already been registered\nClick login to sign in with his email address");
                        document.getElementById("myregusername").focus();
                        return false;
                       }else{   
                        alert("good email address");    
                        return true;
                      }
                    },              
                    error:function(){
                    alert("failure");            
                    }
                });
    } else {
        var errorBorder = "1px solid red";      
        var error = false;
        alert('Please enter a VALID email address');        
        myusername.style.border = errorBorder;
        return false;
    }
}
        } else {
         var errorBorder = "1px solid red";     
         var error = false;
         alert('Please enter a VALID email address');       
         myusername.style.border = errorBorder;
         return false;
       }
}
```

If I remove the ajax call, then it runs fine in Safari.

I have read about Safari caching $post's but I don't have enough knowledge to be able to incorporate what I have found into my code and get it working. I have added the  'headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" }, ' but that still doesnt fix the issue.

if the email is registered then it throws the error message but if the email is not found in the db, it throws the 'emailk good' alert but doesnt return the true to the original statement so the form does not get submitted

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have jQuery already loaded, why not use it all the way? Also you have a typo: `$.post("checkregemail.php",username:myusername},`  should be `$.post("checkregemail.php",{"username":myusername},` - leading { and quotes

Comment: the typo is not in my code its just from when I copied and pasted the relevant parts of the code..now updated. Would the jQuery resolve my Safari issue?

Comment: Possilby not, but  `var myusername = document.getElementById("myregusername");` is ALSO wrong it should be  `var myusername = document.getElementById("myregusername").value;` or `var myusername = $("#myregusername").val();`

Comment: Ive changed that but still no joy. It can find when an email has already been registered and shows the error message but when it doesnt find it in the db it doesnt return the true statement back to the original function so the form can be submitted. I have updated the OP with a reworked ajax call.

Comment: You are aware that your Ajax validation will not return anything in the validate function unless you set async to false?

Comment: no that didnt work, anymore ideas?